# Вывод из group by с order by

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, связался с такой проблемой, вывожу из базы

`select * from mess where idUser='1' GROUP BY gripname ORDER BY id DESC`

Он группирует, все выводит, но единственное, он не выводит их в порядке последний id - первый id (ORDER BY id DESC). Помогите исправить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сортировке в данном случае нет смысла. Не стоит использовать в `select` ничего кроме поля по которому вы группируете и агрегатных функций. Например `postgresql` запретит вам ваш запрос, и будет права.

В качестве варианта вы может использовать что-то типа:

```
select max(id), gripname from mess where idUser='1' GROUP BY gripname ORDER BY max(id) DESC
```

В запросе выше СУБД отсортирует значения по максимальному id попавшему в группировку. Например, есть у вас база со значениями:

```
id=1, gripname=a
id=4, gripname=b
id=5, gripname=a
```

Ответом будет вывод:

```
id=5, gripname=a
id=4, gripname=b
```

Comment: Так и знал, что group блокирует 

Comment: @СашаОсипов скорее субд игнорирует эту сортировку так как это неопределенное поведение.

Comment: спасибо, а то все не мог понять что за фигня происходит